# BI Publisher .rtf template to copy

Tags: bi-publisher

I use a BI Publisher .rtf template to format XML input from a file that is created and then discarded after it is used.  I need to see a copy of the XML.  Is it possible to create a .rtf template that just copies the XML input file to a new file?

Comment: This depends on how you use BI Publisher. In our environment, you would run a query to an XML file and process that XML file with BI Publisher. In this situation, copying the file is a trivial step.

Comment: So what is your setup?

Comment: It's trivial to see the XML in Oracle EBS (E-business suite) which BI Publisher used to generate output. It's a button in the view requests. The XML is also available in the database table that stores the concurrent requests.